# Sencha Ext Js - Add a span/div to form field template then dynamically change contents for a text counter

Tags: extjs

I am new to Ext Js so forgive me if my terminology for certain things is not correct.  What I need is text counter.  Here is what I have so far...

http://jsfiddle.net/gfrobenius/WxNDf/1/

What I need to do is make this code reusable so that all textareas get this feature but I still have the ability to change the normal settings like label, name, id, maxLength, etc...  Does this mean turning it into a class, plugIn, component (sorry still trying to learn terminology)?  Can my afterLabelTextTpl be done simpler?  I've seen examples like:

```
var tpl = new Ext.Template('Name: {name}, Age: {age}');
tpl.apply({name: 'John', age: 25});
```

in the documentation but am not sure how to incorporate it into my code.  Also in my three functions for updating the text count you can see I have the line for getting the component hard-coded to 'gtext' and the line for getting the 'countDownSpan' hard-coded as well.  How do I go about making them just know the parent item?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct when it's good, else this question will stay unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own component and extend from a textarea. Also you're doing 3 times the same thing in your callback function. And the id of your textarea should be unique.

Here's an example of your component:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.form.field.TextArea', {
    alias: 'widget.textareacounter',
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    enforceMaxLength: false,
    maxLength: 1000,

    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, config);
        me.afterLabelTextTpl = ['<span style="margin-left:5px;">(' + me.maxLength + ' char. left)</span>'];
        me.callParent()
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.on({
            keydown: me.calculateCharsLeft,
            keyup: me.calculateCharsLeft,
            afterrender: me.calculateCharsLeft,
            scope: me
        });
        me.callParent();
    },

    calculateCharsLeft: function (textfield, e) {
        var me = this;
        var span = Ext.dom.Query.select('span', me.getEl().dom)[0];
        var remaining = me.maxLength - me.getValue().length;
        span.innerHTML = '(' + remaining + ' char. left)';
    }
});
```

And a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/cpLvK/2/

Comment: Beautiful, just what I was looking for. Duh, on the triplicate code, can't believe I missed that. Thanks for demonstrating how to make a component. Now you wouldn't happen to know how to get a new component like this into Architect 2 as a left-pane item so I can drag-n-drop it at will would you?

Comment: I don't use Sencha Architect, so I can't help you with that.